# Java Hibernate Configuration with Mysql

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I am learning Hibernate and I came accross with this bug, I've tried different ways, but I am still having difficulties to fix it. Any help is really appreciated. Thanks in advance. These are my configurations:

```
    public class HibernateUtil {

        private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

        private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
            try {
                Configuration configuration = new Configuration();// Knows how we want hibernate to perform
                configuration.addAnnotatedClass(User.class);
                return configuration
                           .buildSessionFactory(new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().build());// returns a Session Factory

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException("There was an error building the factory");
            }

        }
        /*
         * Provides our application with access to our singleton.
         * The way the singleton pattern works, that field (sessionFactory)
         * and that method (buildSessionFactory()) our both private, so we
         * cannot access them. However, our public method (getSessionFactory())
         * within that singleton can access the private fields of this class.
         * So, it can return our singleton implementation of the Session Factory.
         */
        public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
            return sessionFactory;
        }
    }

The hibernate.properties file looks like this:

    hibernate.connection.username=infinite
    hibernate.connection.password=skills
    hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ifinances?useSSL=false
    hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

return

```
import org.hibernate.Session;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.close();
    }
}

return 

    The stacktrace error:
    INFO - HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)
    at com.infiniteskills.data.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:18)
    at com.infiniteskills.data.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:11)
    at com.infiniteskills.data.Application.main(Application.java:8)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:20)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'RTZ 3 (????)' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:545)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:513)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:505)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:479)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:489)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:69)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:1606)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:633)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:347)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The server time zone value 'RTZ 3 (????)' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:54)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:73)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.util.TimeUtil.getCanonicalTimezone(TimeUtil.java:118)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.MysqlaSession.configureTimezone(MysqlaSession.java:293)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:2399)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:1739)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:1596)
    ... 34 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.infiniteskills.data.Application.main(Application.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: There was an error building the factory
    at com.infiniteskills.data.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:22)
    at com.infiniteskills.data.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:11)
```

Comment: What's wrong? Any tips, please? I have updated the code.

Comment: "Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'RTZ 3 (????)' is unrecognized" It appears that this is a problem between JDBC and your DB server. I suggest looking for the source of the value of "RTZ 3". Try looking at the server with DB client tool first.

Comment: Steeve11235, You are right.That was the ploblem. I've fixed it by changing the mysql-connector java from 6.0.6 to 5.1.41 and everything is working pretty good. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the answers at your question in following posts :

- [JDBC connection error : unrecognized timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36890422/jdbc-connection-error-unrecognized-timezone)
- [MySQL JDBC Driver 5.1.33 - Time Zone Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515700/mysql-jdbc-driver-5-1-33-time-zone-issue)

hope that helps

Comment: Abass A, Thanks for feedback. I've already found the answer by the link you've provided!