# Troubles with Hibernate and timezone in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I have some troubles with connecting to my mysql server by Hibernate.
StackTrace is talking about, that i have wrong timezone.
That is stacktrace:

```
22:04:36,164 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /SnackLanguage/api/registration: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:78)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:222)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:422)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:213)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:228)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:326)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:812)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at snackLanguage.service.Impl.UsersDaoServiceImpl.openSession(UsersDaoServiceImpl.java:26)
    at snackLanguage.service.Impl.UsersDaoServiceImpl.(UsersDaoServiceImpl.java:23)
    at snackLanguage.service.Impl.UserRegistrationServiceImpl.(UserRegistrationServiceImpl.java:14)
    at snackLanguage.rest.resources.RegistrationResources.(RegistrationResources.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:100)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.resourcefactory.POJOResourceFactory.createResource(POJOResourceFactory.java:53)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:235)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:406)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.buildMetadata(MetadataSources.java:179)
    at snackLanguage.dao.utils.HibernateSessionFactory.buildSessionFactory(HibernateSessionFactory.java:17)
    at snackLanguage.dao.utils.HibernateSessionFactory.(HibernateSessionFactory.java:10)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.(PooledConnections.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.(PooledConnections.java:20)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'EEST' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:545)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:513)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:505)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:479)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:489)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:69)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:1606)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:633)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:347)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
    ... 84 more
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The server time zone value 'EEST' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:54)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:73)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.util.TimeUtil.getCanonicalTimezone(TimeUtil.java:118)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.MysqlaSession.configureTimezone(MysqlaSession.java:293)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:2399)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:1739)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:1596)
    ... 88 more

And trouble in code, on opening hibernate session:

```
 public Session openSession() {
    return HibernateSessionFactory.getSessionFactory().withOptions().jdbcTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")).openSession();
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36890422/jdbc-connection-error-unrecognized-timezone

Comment: The presence of `com.mysql.cj.jdbc` in your stacktrace suggest that you are using a **test** version of MySQL Connector/J 6.x or 8.x. The latest released version is 5.1.46.